# Odd or even full-page float

Tags: floats

I want to place a full-page image after one of the closest page breaks, but I want to control, whether to place this image on ad odd or on an even page.

The closest question I found is this: [Dynamically insert full-page image at nearest page break](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116545/dynamically-insert-full-page-image-at-nearest-page-break).

Probably I should use something like this:

```
    \newcommand{\placeonodd}[1]{%
        \ifeven\c@page{
            \afterpage{
            \thispagestyle{empty}\noindent\includegraphics[height=\textheight]{#1}%
            }}
        \else{---somehow delay \includegraphics until next pagebreak---}
    }
```

Comment: So far I was convinced that for this is enough to use option `p`: `\begin{figure}[p] ... \end{figure}` and it will be placed on the first page after. Or I do missing something in your question?

Comment: @Zarko: Suppose I want all my pictures only on odd pages — what is the right solution for this?

Comment: I see, I miss the point of question. How to do this automatically, I don't know. Manually just put float in text somewhere on even page before. Of course, this require more compilations.

Comment: Maybe you'll be interested to read this post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233113/putting-titles-in-color-boxes/233122#233122

Comment: Probably [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43962/34311) might help, but I do not know how to edit it for my case.

Comment: So the odd-page float must take up the complete page?

Comment: @1010011010: Yes, a complete page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Were you getting `\ifeven` from some package?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{mwe}

\newcommand{\placeonodd}[1]{%
  \ifodd\value{page}\afterpage{\placeonodd{#1}}%
  \else\afterpage{\thispagestyle{empty}\noindent%
    \includegraphics[height=\textheight,width=\textwidth]{#1}}%
  \fi
}
\begin{document}
\placeonodd{example-image}
\lipsum[1-16]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\ifeven` I just imagined in my head, sorry ;-)