# page by page comparison

Tags: alignment, layout

As for my thesis, I need to do a side by side comparison of two calculations.
You can imagine the layout as the following:
On the left page (or first page), I want to discuss the first calculation. On the right page, I want to discuss the second calculation.

In other words, I just want to merge the two sections' pages one by one.
Also one of the calculations is longer than the other, it would be nice if the corresponding page would be left blank.

I am wondering if there is an easy way to do this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you produce two pdf files with the contents, you can on a new file include each page side by side with pdfpages.

Comment: You could use a couple of [p] floats.  Getting them on even and odd pages might be tricky (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255094/odd-or-even-full-page-floate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The scholarly way: eledpar
- the hackish way: solutions with hvfloat (cf. p. 55 of manual), parcolumns or even parallel
- the LaTeX way: side by side minipages
- the easy way: pdfpages, for headings see pagecommand in the manual

But what you ask sounds like math. And maybe in the realms of math other solutions are usual.